# send escape key character with java via telnet

Tags: java, ascii, telnet

I have class which communicates with router through telnet protocol. I can send text strings:

```
    s = new Socket("201.20.2.3",23);
inputStream = s.getInputStream();
outputStream = s.getOutputStream();
outputStream.write( ("admin\n") .getBytes());
Thread.sleep(100);
outputStream.write("24\n".getBytes());
```

So \n acts like an Enter button.
But how to send an Escape button there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Send the ASCII code for escape: `0x1b`.